# Esper: followed by pattern with aggregating criteria

Tags: pattern-matching, esper

I have UsersCount event stream containing count of users connected.
Currently there's a query triggering when number of users drops down by certain percent within certain timeframe:

```
expression Disconnected { x => max(x.usersCount) - x.usersCount }
expression DisconnectedPercent { x => Disconnected(x) / max(x.usersCount) * 100 }
select usersCount, 
       max(usersCount) as maxUsersCount, 
       DisconnectedPercent(users) as disconnectedPercent, 
       Disconnected(users) as disconnectedCount
from UsersCount.win:time(2 min) as users
having DisconnectedPercent(users) >= 30 
   and Disconnected(users) >= 2
output first every 10 minutes
```

Now I need to improve the query to check in a few seconds if users reconnected, i.e. DisconnectedPercent hit some negative threshold, something like:

```
select ... 
from pattern [every UsersCount(DisconnectedPercent >= 30) -> 
   (timer:interval(10 sec) and not UserCount(DisconnectPercent < -10)].win:time(2 min)
```

Right now the solution I implemented needs two statements and one extra stream.
Statement one is:

```
expression Disconnected { x => max(x.usersCount) - x.usersCount } 
expression DisconnectedPercent { x => Disconnected(x) / max(x.usersCount) * 100 }
insert into UsersDisconnectTrigger 
    select usersCount, 
           max(usersCount) as maxUsersCount, 
           Disconnected(users) as disconnectedCount,
           DisconnectedPercent(users) as disconnectedPercent 
from UsersCount.win:time(5 minutes) as users 
having DisconnectedPercent(users) >= 30 and Disconnected(users) >= 10
```

Second statement to register a listener to is:

```
select a.usersCount as usersCount, 
       a.maxUsersCount as maxUsersCount, 
       a.disconnectedCount as disconnectedCount, 
       a.disconnectedPercent as disconnectedPercent 
from pattern [every  a=UsersDisconnectTrigger -> 
           (timer:interval(5 minutes) 
     and not b=UsersCount((usersCount - a.usersCount) / a.usersCount >= 20 / 100)))].win:time(5 minutes)
```

Is there a way to compose single statement to detect such pattern?
Would it be possible to select meaningful values as above?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to look into using "insert-into". 
Have a first statement populate a stream of aggregation values.
Have a second statement consume the stream of the first statement alerting when the threshold oversteps.
have a third statement consume the stream of the first statement alerting when its negative.

Comment: Yes, the approach with two extra streams is obvious. I'm looking for a single-statement solution, that's a limitation of the application we currently have